# Inserting to database after validation has passed using ajax, php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This my signUp.php I dont know what is wrong here that prevents my form values from being inserted into the database

```
<?php
$errors = array();
$data = array();


// validate the variables ======================================================
// if any of these variables don't exist, add an error to our $errors array


    if(empty($_POST["full_Name"])){
        $errors['full_Name'] = "Please fill in yor full name";
    }
    else{
        $full_Name = test_Inputs($_POST['full_Name']);
        //using regular expression to check if the name includes only letters and whitespaces
        if(@!preg_match("/^[A-z\s]*$/", $full_Name)){
            $errors['full_Name'] = "Only alphabets and whitespace";
        }
    }
    if(empty($_POST['user_phoneNumber'])){
        $errors['user_phoneNumber'] = "Mobile number is required";
    }
    else{
        $mobileNumber = test_Inputs($_POST['user_phoneNumber']);
        // using regex to make sure only numbers are inputted in the field
        if(@!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $mobileNumber)){
            $errors['user_phoneNumber'] = "Only numbers allowed";
        }
    }
    if(empty($_POST['user_Email'])){
        $errors['user_Email'] = "Please fill in your email address";
    }
    else{
        $Email = test_Inputs($_POST['user_Email']);
        //using regex to validate email input
        if(@!preg_match("/^[^0-9][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[@][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[.][A-z]{2,4}$/", $Email)){
            $errors['user_Email'] = "Invalid Email address";
        }
    }
    if(empty($_POST['userName'])){
        $errors['userName'] = "User name field is blank";
    }
    else{
        $userName = test_Inputs($_POST['userName']);
        if(@!preg_match("/^[A-z0-9]+$/", $userName)){
            $errors['userName'] = "Only letters and numbers allowed";
        }
    }
    if(empty($_POST['password'])){
        $errors['password'] = "Password field is blank";
    }
    else{
        $password = test_Inputs($_POST['password']);
        if(@!preg_match("/^[A-z0-9]+$/", $password)){
            $errors['password'] = "Only letters and numbers allowed";
        }
        if(strlen($password) < 8){
            $errors['password'] = "Password must be at least 8 characters long";
            $valid = false;
        }
    }
    if(empty($_POST['RPassword'])){
        $errors['RPassword'] = "Confirm your password";
        $valid = false;
    }
    else{
        $RPassword = test_Inputs($_POST['RPassword']);
        if($RPassword != $password){
            $errors['RPassword'] = "Passwords do not match";
        }
    }
    if(!isset($_POST['terms'])){
        $errors['terms'] = "Agree to the terms";
    }
    else {
        $Terms = test_Inputs($_POST['terms']);
    }
// if there are any errors in our errors array, return a success boolean of false
if ( ! empty($errors)) {

    // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors']  = $errors;
} else {

    // if there are no errors process our form, then return a message
    // Inserting into the database
    require_once ('insert_user.php');

    // show a message of success and provide a true success variable
    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Success!';
}
//return all our data on AJAX call
echo json_encode($data);


//creating the test_puts functions
function test_Inputs($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```

This is my dbConn.php

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$db_name = "Interns";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    echo "Connected successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo "Failed to connect" .$ex->getMessage();
}
```

this is my insertUser.php code

```
<?php
require_once ('dbConn.php');

$salt = "cH!swe!retR:";

If(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    try {
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO Users(FullName, MobileNumber, Email, Username, Password)
                          VALUES(:user_name, :user_mobile, :user_email, :user_username, :user_pass)");
        $stmt->bindParam(":user_name", $full_Name);
        $stmt->bindParam(":user_mobile", $mobileNumber);
        $stmt->bindParam(":user_email", $Email);
        $stmt->bindParam(":user_username", $userName);
        $stmt->bindParam(":user_pass", $password);

        $full_Name = $_POST['full_Name'];
        $mobileNumber = $_POST['user_phoneNumber'];
        $Email = $_POST['user_Email'];
        $userName = $_POST['userName'];
        $password = SHA1(($_POST['password']), $salt);
        $stmt->execute();

        echo "Query successful";
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        echo "Query Failed" . $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
$dbh = null;
```

This is my signUp.js

```
// signUpValidation.js
$(document).ready(function() {

    // process the form
    $('form').submit(function(event) {

        $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); // remove the error class
        $('.help-block').remove(); // remove the error text

        // get the form data
        // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
        var formData = {
            'full_Name'                 : $('input[name=full_Name]').val(),
            'user_phoneNumber'          : $('input[name=user_phoneNumber]').val(),
            'user_Email'    : $('input[name=user_Email]').val(),
            'userName' : $('input[name=userName]').val(),
            'password' : $('input[name=password]').val(),
            'RPassword' : $('input[name=RPassword]').val()
        };

        // process the form
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url         : 'signUpValidation.php', // the url where we want to POST
            data        : formData, // our data object
            dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
            encode      : true
        })
        // using the done promise callback
            .done(function(data) {

                // log data to the console so we can see
                console.log(data);

                // here we will handle errors and validation messages
                if ( ! data.success) {

                    // handle errors for name ---------------
                    if (data.errors.full_Name) {
                        $('#name-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#name-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.full_Name + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for email ---------------
                    if (data.errors.user_phoneNumber) {
                        $('#mobile-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#mobile-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.user_phoneNumber + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                    // handle errors for superhero alias ---------------
                    if (data.errors.user_Email) {
                        $('#email-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#email-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.user_Email + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }
                    if (data.errors.userName) {
                        $('#username-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#username-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.userName + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }
                    if (data.errors.password) {
                        $('#password-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#password-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.password + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }
                    if (data.errors.RPassword) {
                        $('#retypePassword-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input
                        $('#retypePassword-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.RPassword + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input
                    }

                } else {

                    // ALL GOOD! just show the success message!
                    $('form').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + '</div>');

                    // usually after form submission, you'll want to redirect
                    // window.location = '/thank-you'; // redirect a user to another page

                }
            })

            // using the fail promise callback
            .fail(function(data) {

                // show any errors
                // best to remove for production
                console.log(data);
            });

        // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

I would be glad if someone puts me through. Please note I sent the form through an AJAX call to the signUp.php.

Comment: may be VALUES should be in single quotes like this
VALUES('$username','$password');   in insertUser.php

Comment: **WARNING**: Using the error-suppressing `@` operator obscures problems with your code and makes debugging issues a whole lot more complicated. That's a tool of last resort and should only be used in exceptional circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about this in your AJAX code: url: 'signUpValidation.php',
sinse your file is signUp.php?

That is a lot of code but you are calling signUp.php then require_once ('insert_user.php'); in it and then in insert_user you are using $_POST["full_Name"] again even when you validated it already in signUp.php. Shouldn't insert_user.php just make the query in the DB?

And you are checking If(isset($_POST['submit'])) in insert_user.php. You should check it in signUp.php.

I would organize the code in functions at least if not classes: functionConnectToDB, fnInsertUser...

signUp.php:

```
require_once('functions.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    validations you have
}

if (empty($errors)) {
    fill $data array with $full_Name etc. cause you didn't do it!
    insertUser($data);
}
```

functions.php:

```
function connectDB() {
    ...
}
function insertUser($data) {
    connectDB();
    insert DB query
    ...
}
```

Comment: can you please show me what you mean with a code snippet